# Error while executing in Android Studio Giraffe

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile-development

I just ran Android Studio Giraffe version 2022.3.1 Patch 2, created a new project called *TestApp* wtih *Empty Views Activity* and just wanted to run the app in virtual device. I came into an issue with `compileSdk` and `targetSdk` - they needed to be updated from `33` to `34`. No changes in `MainActivity.java`, `activity_main.xml` or `AndroidManifest.xml` were made. However then when I wanted to run the app again, the following issue appeared in red popup:

```
Error running 'app':
Error while executing 'am start -n "com.example.testapp/com.example.testapp.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER --splashscreen-show-icon'
```

How do I resolve that please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your **compile/targetSDK** version to **34**.
Check whether your **activity/package** name is correct, and declared in `AndroidManifest` too. If `splashScreen` requires any permission, ask for them in `manifest.xml`.

Comment: I have already updated compileSdk and targetSdk version to 34 as I wrote. For sure I once again checked the AndroidManifest and everything seems fine. However problem is still present.